# how to set custom attribute value in ms dynamic CRM from Android crmsdk2015?

Tags: android, dynamics-crm

i have added 1 attributes its name "new_city" and Display name "City". when i add this attributes sdk give the following error

> 400 bad request

without this attributes its works perfect.

please check below code

```
 Appointment app = Appointment.build()
            .setSubject("android")
            .setScheduledStart(mDate.getTime())
            .setScheduledEnd(mDate1.getTime())
            .setDescription("info")
            .setNew_City("Ahmedabad");


 try {
        RestOrganizationServiceProxy restService = new RestOrganizationServiceProxy(mOrgService);
        restService.Create(app,new Callback<UUID>() {
            @Override
            public void success(UUID uuid, Response response) {
                log("sucess", uuid.toString());

                      }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                displayError(error.toString());
                log("error", error.toString());
            }
        });
    }
    catch(InvalidClassException ex) {
        displayError(ex.getMessage());
        log("msg",ex.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is city an option set (drop down) in CRM? if so, you will have to pass on the value of the option set (integer), not the label. To get the value of the option set navigate to Customizations and look up the attribute properties.